# Percolation threshold

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Percolation threshold is a mathematical concept related to percolation theory, which is the formation of long-range connectivity in random systems. Below the threshold a giant connected component does not exist; while above it, there exists a giant component of the order of system size.

How can we calculate a percolation threshold of a graph/network using *Mathematica*?

1. Image of a subcellular network: [image]
2. The image is transformed into a graph by utilizing `MorphologicalGraph` function: [image]
3. By applying the `ConnectedComponents` function and choosing the list of subgraphs from the suggestion menu one can  obtain a soup of graphs/networks. Here are the top of that list: [image]

The question is how to exctract the probability that these networks are being connected? What is the critical treshold or bond percolation?

Comment: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PercolationOnASquareGrid/

Comment: [This Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85185/mimic-a-procedural-recursive-clustering-algorithm-for-site-percolation-using-fu) might also be of interest.

Comment: @Feyre. Thank you so much.

Comment: i don't follow the probabilistic nature of the question. If you have many such images you could see how many show long range connectivity. Otherwise its not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @george2079.Thank you for your consideration. I actually found this nice paper of  Prof Oliver Knill "MATHEMATICA ROUTINES FOR INDEX EXPECTATION AND PERCOLATION " which kind of address the challenges I am dealing with at this point. Would appreciate any comments about what the code given actually does to define the site and bond percolations.

Comment: @george2079. Here is one of the codes  Prof Knill gave:

Comment: my point is the probability will depend on the statistical nature of how the stuff in your image might vary. If you only have the one image you cant say anything about probability. (or perhaps if you know something about the physics of what you are looking at you could do something.)

Comment: @george2079. I have many images  of thousands of cells/networks under different conditions but that is not my concern now. What I need  is some guidance/help with;  is to actually understand  what the WL utilized to calculate the percolation metrics in that paper does/means.   Any suggestions or ideas , commenst on the Knill's code/description ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a symmetric matrix of random positive weights.

```
mybasicweightmatrix = (temp = Table[RandomReal[], {10}, {10}]) + 
   Transpose[temp]; (* symmetric matrix of random positive weights *)
```

Then threshold the entries such that values less than `mythreshold` will be set to $0$ (not connected), others to $1$ (connected).  Form a graph based on this thresholded adjacency matrix.  Then adjust `mythreshold` until the graph is no longer weakly connected.

```
Manipulate[
 thresholdedmatrix = (HeavisideTheta[# - mythreshold] & /@ 
    mybasicweightmatrix);

 myfig = Column[{mythreshold, 
    WeaklyConnectedGraphQ[nn = AdjacencyGraph[thresholdedmatrix]], 
    Graph[nn, GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"]}],

 {mythreshold, 0, 2}]
```

Here "weakly connected" means there is a path from any vertex to any other vertex.  Seems like a reasonable specification of a "giant component."

[image]

[image]

Comment: G.Stork. Thank you very much. I am a neophyte to programming in general  and WL in particular. Do you mind please  describing  what the code actually does. I am very appreciative.

Comment: @ G.Stork. Many Thanks!

Comment: Pure Function:  You're welcome.  Will you be using this in some publication or research?